# jQuery ajax jsonp request. Как получить данные?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Есть  запрос который получает json с удаленного сервера, в инструментах разработчика вижу успех.[image: Скриншот инструментов разработчика нунл хром]

Но не могу получить доступ к данным json, их видно в  вкладке prewview но когда вывожу в консоль пишет undefined.

Напишите пожалуйста почему я дурак и как это исправить.

function myRequest(){

```
        $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://site.com/mycustom.json",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    async: true,
                    data: {},
                    jsonpCallback:"logResults",

                    success: function(data) {
                    console.log("Request done!");
                        }


                    });                 
        }
```

function logResults(response){
                console.log(response)}

$(document).on( "pageinit","#main", function(){

```
    $('#btnDownload').click(function( event ){
        myRequest();
        logResults();

    });




});
```

Comment: Во-первых, чтобы что-то выводилось в `logResults` надо в него что-то передавать `logResults(ВОТ_ЗДЕСЬ);` ..... а во-вторых: ajax — асинхронная функция.....поэтому ответ как взять результат после ajax запроса смотри в ссылке выше

Comment: Спасибо. Без вас угробил бы на это еще 2 дня.